# Akka DistributedPubSubMediator at-least-once delivery guarantees for publishing to a topic

Tags: scala, akka, publish-subscribe

I need to have at-least-once delivery guarantees for messages published to a DistributedPubSubMediator topic.

I looked into DistributedPubSubMediator.scala and can see the following in TopicLike trait (Akka 2.4.6):

```
trait TopicLike extends Actor {
  var subscribers = Set.empty[ActorRef]

  def defaultReceive: Receive = {
    case msg ?
      subscribers foreach { _ forward msg }
  }
}
```

However I couldn't find any method to retrieve subscribers set from mediator... It would be great if there was a message request GetTopicSubscribers which would expose this information to mediator clients:

```
mediator ! GetTopicSubscribers("mytopic")
```

So after publishing to a topic the publisher could wait for Ack messages from all active subscribers. Is there any other way to accomplish something like that?
It would be great if somehow akka.contrib.pattern.ReliableProxy can be plugged in into DistributedPubSubMediator.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your publisher to ask the mediator for the count of subscribers via a [akka.cluster.pubsub.DistributedPubSubMediator.CountSubscribers](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/cluster/pubsub/DistributedPubSubMediator.CountSubscribers.html)("myTopic")

Then it just needs to keep a count of how many Ack messages it gets from subscribers.

No need to track actual subscribers or which ones have Acknowledged, when your Ack count reaches the subscriber count you know they have all received it (thanks to Akka at-most-once delivery reliability)

Note however this comment in the [source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-cluster-tools/src/main/scala/akka/cluster/pubsub/DistributedPubSubMediator.scala#L223):

```
// Only for testing purposes, to poll/await replication
case object Count
final case class CountSubscribers(topic: String)
```

Suggests perhaps CountSubscribers is not something to rely on too heavily?